# How to search Item by Item custom field in NetSuite Suitelet

Tags: javascript, scripting, netsuite

As the title say, I am trying to create suitelet searching for items by custom field. but having issues.
Error says invalid filter or id.

```
function main(request, response) {

var search_filters = new Array();
search_filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem_itemcategory', null, 'is','Add-on Items');

var search_columns = new Array();
search_columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid');
search_columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('displayname');
search_columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('storedisplayname');
search_columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('storedescription');
search_columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('storedetaileddescription');
search_columns[5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('storedisplayimage');
search_columns[6] = new nlobjSearchColumn('storedisplaythumbnail');
search_columns[7] = new nlobjSearchColumn('onlineprice');
search_columns[8] = new nlobjSearchColumn('outofstockmessage');

var search_item_list = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,search_filters,search_columns);

response.setContentType('JSON');
response.write(JSON.stringify({'addonitems':search_item_list}));
}
```

Where Item custom field "custitem_itemcategory", is a multiselect type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'is', use 'anyof', then specify the internalId of the custitem_itemcategory.

Comment: Hi @suite-resources, i am still noob in NetSuite scripting. can you please site some example how? 

Thank you. Something like this you mean?


search_filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem_itemcategory', null, 'anyof', 'Add On Items');

Comment: nlobjSearchFilter('custitem_itemcategory', null, 'anyof', 1);